# Why is this set of $2 \times 2$ matrices of real numbers a nonabelian group under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

My book wrote something like this

> Consider $M_{2}^*(\mathbb{R}) = \left \{ A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) :  \det(A) \neq 0\right \}$
>
> $A = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
> 1 &1 \\ 
> 1 &0 
> \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and B = $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
> 0 &1 \\ 
> 1 &1
> \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $AB \neq BA$
>
> It follows that ($M_{2}^*(\mathbb{R})$, . ) is a nonabelian group

My confusions

1. If it is nonabelian, then it is not commutative. That is the identity property $AI \neq IA = A$ isn't satisified. The same goes for the inverse
2. In my lecture my professor just wrote ($M_{2}^*(\mathbb{R})$, . ) and told us that this is a Monoid (and not a group) because he told us that a * on top of a group means without zero (matrix here). And he wrote that because not all 2 x 2 matrices are invertible. Which confuses the notations people generally use. But what he wrote (in my notes) seem to contradict the book's example

Can someone clarify my confusion?

Comment: $AI = IA = A$ holds for matrices.  "not commutative" does not mean "never commutative".  It just means that in *some* (not *all*) cases, $AB \ne BA$.

Comment: *All* of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a (multiplicative) monoid. If you remove the zero matrix, you still have a monoid, but it is still not a group since it has noninvertible elements. Affixing $^\ast$ refers to the invertible elements only, which does form a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group $G$ is defined as *abelian* if $AB=BA$ **for all** $A,B \in G$.  In the case of $G=M^*_2(\mathbb{R})$, this is not true (as the example you cite shows).

It's not hard to find examples of elements $A,B \in G$ that commute in any arbitrary group $G$ (whether or not it's abelian), such as when $A=B$, when $A$ is the identity or when $A=B^{-1}$.  But, when determining whether or not $G$ is abelian, the important point is whether or not this is true **for all** pairs of elements $A,B \in G$.

As for the second part, I'm guessing your professor wrote $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e., $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$) is a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) (since it contains non-invertible elements -- but satifies the other group axioms under matrix multiplication).  You don't want to throw away the $0$-matrix, since then it wouldn't be closed under multiplication, e.g. \[\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}\right).\]

Comment: no he wrote both $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $M_2(\mathbb{R})^*$. The former was clear to me, but not the latter one

Comment: $M_2^*(\mathbb{R})$ should be where we throw out the non-invertible elements, as per the definition in your question (in $M_2^*(\mathbb{R})$, we throw out the all $0$-matrix, along with every other non-invertible matrix).

Answer (score 4):

Abealian means that $AB=BA$ for all $A.B$. Thus nonabelian means $AB\ne BA$ for *some* $A.B$. Especially, you may (and actually do) have $AI=IA$ and $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}$ in a nonabelian group.

The notation in question is indeed sometimes used confusingly. I had preferred $M^\times$ instead of $M^*$ for what your book writes, where $M^\times $ explicitly denotes the *units* of a ring, i.e. the elements that happen to have a multiplicative inverse. There are simply too many things that can be denoted by adding a star.

Comment: I haven't learned what a ring is. I am sorry